# Problema com if-else

Tags: javascript, html

Criei esta código para ver se você é um estrangeiro nos EUA.
Porém quando eu digito qualquer coisa, ele so me retorna 'Voce e estrangeiro.', nunca me retorna o 'Voce e Estadunidense', mesmo que eu digite 'EUA'.
O que eu faço?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>a</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste para ver se você é um estrangeiro nos EUA.</h1>
    Em que pais você nasceu? <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
    <input type="button" value="CHECAR" onclick="checar()">
    <div id = 'res'>
    </div>
    <script>
        function checar() {
        var pais = document.getElementById('pais')
        var res = document.getElementById('res')
        if (pais == 'EUA'){
            res.innerHTML = 'Voce e Estadunidense.'
        } else {
            res.innerHTML = 'Voce e estrangeiro.'

        }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Na sua função `checar`, verifique pelo valor do elemento. Pois como está fazendo no momento:

```
    var pais = document.getElementById('pais')
```

A variável `pais` vai ter um [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) nela por ter chamado a função [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). Isso é uma referência a um elemento da página. Para resgatar o valor, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira, verificando também se conseguiu encontrar o elemento:

```
if (pais) {
    if (pais.value == "EUA") {
        // uma coisa
    } else {
        // outra coisa
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Você também pode colocar [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) logo após você ter chamado a função [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). que ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```html
let pais = document.getElementById('pais').value
```

assim também irá atender oque você precisa:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checar estrangeiro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Teste para ver se você é um estrangeiro nos EUA.</h1>
    <label for="pergunt">
        Em que pais você nasceu?
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="pais" id="pais">
    <input type="button" value="CHECAR" onclick="checar()">
    <div id = 'res'>
    </div>
    <script>
        function checar() {
        let pais = document.getElementById('pais').value
        let res = document.getElementById('res')
        
        if (pais == 'EUA'){
            res.textContent = 'Você é estadunidence';
        } else {
            res.textContent = 'Você é estrangeiro';
        }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```